# Unescaping Specific Escaped HTML Tags

Tags: java, html, ms-word, apache-poi, html-escape-characters

### Backstory

I have a situation where I recieve a byte array that may be a type of word document ( out of 3 possibilities):

1. Word 97 binary
2. HTML masqarading as Word with Custom MS Word Tags
3. Word 2013 binary

Currently I am handling 1, and 2. 
If parsing for 1) fails, I currently assume the document is HTML.
Unfortunately, the document contains certain escaped HTML tags (as textual content), that I need to unescape in order to pass onward to processing code developed by other people (CMS import, etc).

### Current Implementation

Below please see my current implementation using Apache POI for 1) , and switching to String manipulation for my need to unescape `Poetr` and `Articl` tags.

**If there is a more efficient way to do this using a regex please advise.**

```
 private void handleWordDocument(Byte[] bytes) {
    //Parse DOC file
    WordExtractor extractor = null;

    try
    {
      InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
      HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
      extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
      StringBuilder poetryIntroAndContent = new StringBuilder();

      String text = extractor.getText();  //Escaped HTML looks liks HTML as text
      attributions.setAttributionsFile(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));          
    }
    catch (Exception exep)
    {
      LOG.info("Parsing word file failed using Apache POI for word97:" + exep.toString()+". Will attempt to parse file with HTML reader after unescaping html tags.");
      try {
        String content = new String(attributions.getAttributionsFile(),"UTF-8");
        //content = content.replaceAll("&lt;[/]?Poetry(.*?)&gt;","<Poetry$0>").replaceAll("Poetry&lt;","").replaceAll("");
        String[] segments = content.split("&lt;");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String extraDebug = "";

        for(String segment: segments){
          int endTag = -1;

//          //TODO: MBAK: Remove this
//          if(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 < 1481328000){ //December 10, 2016
//            extraDebug = "-Testing Translation" + System.currentTimeMillis();
//          }

          if(segment.length() < 5){ stringBuilder.append(segment+extraDebug); continue;}

          String segmentSubstring = segment.substring(0,6);

          if(!(
              segmentSubstring.toLowerCase().equals("poetry") ||
                  segmentSubstring.toLowerCase().equals("/poetr") ||
                  segmentSubstring.toLowerCase().equals("articl") ||
                  segmentSubstring.toLowerCase().equals("/artic")
              )
              ){
            stringBuilder.append(segment); continue;
          }

          String[] segments2 = segment.split("&gt;");

          if(segments2.length < 2){  stringBuilder.append(segment); continue; }

          segments2[0] = "<" + segments2[0].replaceAll("&quot;","\"") + ">";

          int counter=0;
          for(String subsegment: segments2){
            stringBuilder.append(subsegment);          }
          }

        attributions.setAttributionsFile(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you are using a library (POI) to help you parse word documents, have you considered a library to help you parse HTML? A quick Google search brought up https://jsoup.org/

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Can JSOUP parse `escaped` HTML as an element and automatically convert to a DOM/Document element object/tree? What you said did give me an idea, I could try `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(document.html());`. However, since I only want a subset of escaped html (not all tags), I could detect all new unescaped HTML tags (by keeping a record/map if possible), and re-escape all tags that I don't wish to unescape. Another better option would be to modify the method `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(document.html());` itself to only do the tags I want.

Comment: I don't know. Jsoup is an HTML parser for Java. I haven't used it.